# Android : how to shorten string in textview

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to shorten this string, for example it shows only 4 characters, and the rest becomes ...

```
String a = "Jhonatan Smith";
```

can it be like this? results :

```
Jhon...
```

is there any solution for this?

Comment: You can do it manually to cut off the string. 
yourTextView.setText(a.substring(0, 4) + "...");
But remember to make sure the string has 4 chars or more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a `TextView` you can use [setEllipsize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setEllipsize(android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt)) so words in the text that are longer than the view's width to be ellipsized instead of broken in the middle.